# How to make one event listener for multiple same components in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, frontend

I'm trying to add an event listener for whole document in a component, Since I'm using multiple of those components its duplicating event listeners, Is there a way to optimize this?

Here is my component -

```
export default function Dropdown(props) {
  const [showDropdown, setShowDropdown] = useState(false);

  function closeDropdown(event) {
    if (!event.target.parentElement.classList.contains('dropdown')) {
      setShowDropdown(false);
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('click', closeDropdown);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('click', closeDropdown);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className='dropdown-container dropdown'>
    // some html here
    </div>
  );
}
```

Parent Component -

```
export default function Preference() {
  return (
    <div className="container">
        <Dropdown
          list={Object.values(DIFFICULTY)}
          placeholderText="difficulty"
          size="size-1"
        />
      <Dropdown
        list={Object.values(CATEGORIES)}
        placeholderText="category"
        size="size-2"
      />
      <Link to="/quiz">
        <button className="btn-large">Take Quiz</button>
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Event listeners as seen in dev tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifaTo.png)

I could potentially use custom hook for this but I'm not sure if it will not lead to duplicated listeners.

Comment: Using a global event listener can cause a lot of performance issues. I recommend you pass a property to the child that determines whether or not the child is open and handling the states in the parent.

Comment: I'll still need document click event listener to listen for click. Also I have two of same components I'll need to make two different states right? That won't be scalable if I do decide to add more dropdowns.

Comment: Instead of a global event you could try and use something like `onBlur` on the div and close it that way

Comment: That would require for component to be in focus, it would create a new challenge instead of solving previous one. I know webpages should be accessible but that would come at a later stage for me.